# update product websites on magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, command

I have come across posts to update products websites programmatically for Magento 1. However, I do not find the same for Magento 2. Ideally, a command would really be useful.

Can somebody help with writing a command in M2 to add/remove websites to a product and ideally to a list of product ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I took the time to write a command-line to implement this needs.

running `php bin/magento mbs:websites:update '1,2,3,4,5' '1,2'`

will update the product whose id are 1, 2 , 3, 4 and 5 to be assigned to the website ids 1 and 2 only regardless of their previous context.

Of course, this is subject to each ids do exist and it did work with this in mind for me.

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\ProductWebsiteUpdate\Command;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UpdateWebsites extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action
     */
    private $action;
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $action,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        string $name = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('mbs:websites:update');
        $this->setDescription('Update a product websites');

        $this->addArgument('product_ids', InputArgument::REQUIRED);
        $this->addArgument('website_ids', InputArgument::REQUIRED);
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addIdFilter($this->getProductIds($input));

        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $this->action->updateWebsites(
                [$product->getId()],
                $product->getWebsiteIds(),
                'remove'
            );

            $this->action->updateWebsites(
                [$product->getId()],
                $this->getWebsiteIds($input),
                'add'
            );
        }

        $output->writeln('done');
    }

    private function getProductIds(InputInterface $input)
    {
        if (strpos($input->getArgument('product_ids'), ',')!==false) {
            return explode(',', $input->getArgument('product_ids'));
        }

        return [$input->getArgument('product_ids')];
    }

    private function getWebsiteIds(InputInterface $input)
    {
        if (strpos($input->getArgument('website_ids'), ',')!==false) {
            return explode(',', $input->getArgument('website_ids'));
        }

        return [$input->getArgument('website_ids')];
    }
```

Comment: But image roles weren't copied, how can we add image roles?